# How to add a scroller to the nesting element of the react-virtualize Table?

Tags: reactjs, nested, react-virtualized

There are several components with dynamic size inside one `div`. One of those components would be a `react-virtualized` `Table`.
How would you implement it to have just one scroller in the parent `div`?
It seems like `WindowSroller` won't help, since I want to have a page without common scroller, but with two separate ones instead. One for `Column A` and one for `Column B`.

```
||================================================================================||
||                                 Some static header                             ||
||================================================================================||
                   Column A                                     Column B 
||========================================||   ||=================================||
||                                        ||   ||                                 ||
||      A component with dynamic height   ||   ||                                 ||
||                                        ||   ||                                 ||
||========================================||   ||                                 ||
||||====================================||||   ||                                 ||
||||                                    ||||   ||                                 ||
||||   Component with dynamic height    ||||   ||  Component with dynamic height  ||
||||                                    ||||   ||                                 ||
||||====================================||||   ||                                 ||
||||====================================||||   ||                                 ||
||||                                    ||||   ||                                 ||
||||      react-virtualized Table       ||||   ||                                 ||
||||                                    ||||   ||                                 ||
||||====================================||||   ||                                 ||
||========================================||   ||=================================||
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly at a glance, I don't think this is a case RV handles out of the box. You can probably fork `WindowScroller` though and use it (or something similar).

Comment: @brianvaughn would it be possible to use `WindowScroller` just for one part of a page?

Comment: Well, yes- if you want the whole page to be scrollable. If both columns A and B in your drawing above are within a scroll container that _is not_ the window then you'd need to fork `WindowScroller`.

Comment: @brianvaughn it doesn't seem to be that hard to fork WindowScroller and create some ScrollingContainer. Does this component make sense as a part of react-virtualized? I could try to create a pull request if it would make sense.

Comment: If it's super trivial (aka not much maintenance burden for me) and you think it would be generically useful, sure. I'd be happy to review it. :)